# how to add associations in class rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I trying to do like

```
@array_object.factets
```

this `@array_object` belongs to `Class A`

```
 class A
   factets = ['c','d','e']
 end
```

`Class A` is not inheriting any `Active record`

Answer (score 0):

if not necessary calling variable then you can easily do:

```
class A
  def factets
     ['c','d','e']
  end
end
```

and then:

```
@array_object = A.new
@array_object.factets
```

OR for single line of code:

```
@array_object = A.new.factets
```